# Great speedy reaction to Spam

Tags: discussion

Immediately after answering a question on ambulance response time targets, I saw a blatant spam posting which was immediately pounced on by our brilliant community.

Just wanted to praise those who acted so quickly to take it down. When I downvoted and flagged it, the downvotes jumped to -7 and within seconds the post was removed.

Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the help page, specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](//medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)'s last section: *Avoid overt self-promotion*. You might also be interested in [How to not be a spammer](//medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).

Keep up the good work everybody and flag the spam like we did here.

Comment: The most likely post you seem to refer to was autoflagged by the [smokedetector system](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1181/the-fire-department). That alerts to quick action. Take a look at transcript, votes, views and timeline. You may thank a community that doesn't look around much here on meta. It was indeed quite obviously *pure* SPAM, and nothing bordering "excessive" ('genuine post with benefits').

Comment: Ah, you are correct @LangLangC - The post is mentioned in the log.